# Cannot specialize non-generic type ResponseSerializer

Tags: swift2, alamofire

From the [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#generic-response-object-serialization) and the [2.0 Migrate Guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%202.0%20Migration%20Guide.md) I tried to use `Response Serialization` but I'm having the following errors. I can't seem to figure out the problems. I'm also having the same errors with `ResponseCollectionSerializable`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `GenericResponseSerializer` that conforms to `ResponseSerializer`:

```
public protocol ResponseObjectSerializable {
    init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject)
}

extension Request {
    public func responseObject<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result<T>) -> Void) -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = GenericResponseSerializer<T> { request, response, data in
            let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
            let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, data)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                if let
                    response = response,
                    responseObject = T(response: response, representation: value)
                {
                    return .Success(responseObject)
                } else {
                    let failureReason = "JSON could not be serialized into response object: \(value)"
                    let error = Error.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                    return .Failure(data, error)
                }
            case .Failure(let data, let error):
                return .Failure(data, error)
            }
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

`ResponseSerializer` is the protocol in which all response serializers must conform to.

Comment: What does `GenericResponseSerializer that conforms to ResponseSerializer` mean?

Comment: I found it. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/2.0.2#generic-response-object-serialization You can edit the answer including this code. It was cause I was using 3.0 code not 2.0.2

Comment: I added code to answer. I mean that `Request.response` method accepts `ResponseSerializer` as first argument and `GenericResponseSerializer` is Alamofire build-it generic class that comforms (implements) to `ResponseSerializer` protocol and can be used to provide automatic, type-safe response object serialization.